# How is it possible to set an extension_attributes to the orders and have it appear with REST/SOAP API?

Tags: magento2, api, soap, extension-attributes

I am trying to use extension_attributes in order to add a field in the orders. The thing is, I want that field to appear when we get the orders with API calls (`http://monsite.fr/soap/default?services=salesOrderRepositoryV1`) and I can't get this to work.

For now I altered the tables `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid` with the Setup of my module (InstallSchema) to add a field "file_name" and declared `extension_attributes.xml` in etc :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="file_name" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I've got the generated class in vendor with the methods getFileName and setFileName, but that's it, when I try the url
`http://monsite.fr/soap/default?services=salesOrderRepositoryV1`
I still have the ordinary attributes (entityId, createdAt, incrementId, etc.), there is not a fileName attribute (not even in extension_attributes node, of course).

Is there someone who knows how to get an extension attribute to appear with API ?

**EDIT**

Okay, now I get the field "fileName" in the `<extensionAttributes>` of the SOAP response, but it doesn't retrieve the values in database...
I added a plugin in di.xml :

`<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="get_file_name" type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\FileGet"/>`

and I implemented a function `afterGet()` where I have access to the extension attributes (`$orderInterface->getExtensionAttributes()`) and call the generated methods `getFileName()` and `setFileName()`, but getFileName() return null...

One more thing, I also tried with an Observer on the event `<event name="sales_order_load_after">`, and here I can call getData('file_name') to have database values, but it is done without passing by extension attributes, I'm a little bit confuse, here.

To summ it up :

-with the plugin on `OrderRepositoryInterface` and the function `afterGet()`, I have acces to the `extension_attributes` of my order, and can call `getFileName()` and `setFileName()` methods (generated in `OrderExtensionInterface`), but doing so doesn't seem to affect the database;

-with the `Observer` : on the event `sales_order_load_after`, I can use `getdata('file_name')` as if file_name were a basic attribute and not an extension_atributes, and it *does* retrieve the value in database, but then it is not present in the SOAP response.

I don't know if I am clear enough, feel free to ask more questions, or sample code if needed.

**EDIT**

It appears that even if we don't have auto-implementation for it, it is possible to call `getData('file_name')` through the `$resultOrder` (class `OrderInterface`) of the `afterGet` method of the plugin. Now I have to do a similar work in order to set the value with a SOAP request.

I hope that this monologue of mine can help someone^^". feel free to post a question if you also have some trouble with extension_attributes, I'll help if I can.

Comment: That definitely helps, did you get any further?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the info! Did you ever get to the point where you have a complete get and set for an extension_attribute via REST API? I managed to configure the get, but can't manage to set a new value to it. I don't get errors, but the new value isn't stored in the DB. Is that a limitation?

Comment: @justabuzz can you please share how you managed to configure the get method with new extension attributes?